# $x_n\to x$ weakly for some $x$ in $X$ with $\|x\| = 1$, then show that $\|x_n- x\|^2 \to 0$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ X$ be a Hilbert space and $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $ X$. If
$\|x_n\| \le 1$ and $x_n\to x$ weakly for some $x$ in $X$ with $\|x\| = 1$,
then show that $\|x_n- x\|^2 \to 0$.

---

Here we just need to show that $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$ using the fact $x_n\to x$ weakly for some $x$ in $X$ with $\|x\| = 1$, but I am confuse to doing this as I get
$\|x_n\|^2=\langle x_n,x_n\rangle =\langle x,x_n\rangle =\langle x,x\rangle  =\|x\|^2$ as the norm function is continuous.But here no use of the given fact.
can somebody guide me properly.thanks for your time.

Comment: Please use `\langle` and `\rangle` to get $\langle$ and $\rangle$. The relation symbols `<` and `>` not only look different, they give wrong spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Combine $\langle x_n,x\rangle\to\langle x,x\rangle=1$ and $\lvert\langle x_n,x\rangle\rvert\le\lVert x_n\rVert\cdot\lVert x\rVert=\lVert x_n\rVert$.

Then use $\lVert x_n-x\rVert^2=\lVert x_n\rVert^2-2\operatorname{Re}\langle x_n,x\rangle+\lVert x\rVert^2$.

Comment: Better than mine, I didn't notice it until I posted.  I left out the last part because poton seems to indicate they've reduced it to showing that $\|x_n\|\to\|x\|$, but your inclusion of it is probably more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect to assume that $\langle x_n,x_n\rangle=\langle x,x_n\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle$.  (In particular, $n$ is not quantified here.)

In general, if $(a_n)$ converges weakly to $a$, then $\|a\|\leq \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} \|a_n\|$. This is because $\|a\|^2=\langle a,a\rangle =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\langle a,a_n\rangle|\leq\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\|a\|\|a_n\|$.

Applying this to your situation, you have $1\leq\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\|$, and combined with $\|x_n\|\leq 1$ for all $n$, this implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\|=1$, as desired.

Comment: I'm probably overlooking something, but how would $\lim \|x_n\| = 1$ imply $\|x_n - x \| \to 0$?

Comment: @Sanchez: See the hint at the end of Harald's answer.  In general, if $x_n\to x$ weakly and $\|x_n\|\to\|x\|$, then $\|x_n-x\|\to 0$, and I had the impression from poton's post that they already are familiar with that fact.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks!